# Define a COM class that is only createable from the same EXE where it is registered

Tags: multithreading, com

1. If have an EXE with a STA in the main thread
2. Inside the EXE a second thread with another STA is created.
3. This second thread with the STA should publish a class factory with CoRegisterClassObject that is only available from this process.

When I use CoRegisterClassObject with `CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER` and REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE the main thread creates the object with `CLSCTX_ALL` I get the error "class not registered".

When I use `CoRegisterClassObject` with `CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER` and `REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE` the main thread can create the object. But the next instance of the program will create the object inside the first process.

Using `CLSCTX_INPROC` flag inside `CoCreateInstance` will always say that the class is not registered.

BTW: Because I register the class by my own always when the program is started there are no registry keys except the required one the the typelib.

More detailed explanation why I need this:
The created class uses pointers and function internally created in the context of the EXE. Just think that I am programming an "Application" object that should support only functions inside this process and files and objects managed by this session. And I need this COM object because it is used inside a VBScripting Host and is again exposed to other COM objects.

Is there a way to registering a class factory that only support creation from inside my EXE?

Comment: What's the benefit to having these be COM at all if they're just classes creatable within the same process?

Comment: The reason is, that the created class uses pointers and function internally created in the context of the EXE. Just think that I am programming an "Application" object that should support only functions inside this process and files and objects managed by this session.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever's point is that there is no need to make these classes COM objects at all. Just make them conventional C++ classes. COM is an inter-component communication mechanism.

Comment: Yes... but I need this COM objects internally again because I have a VBScript host that exposes this pointer!

Comment: Because some guys think that I don't understand what I am asking I extend my question with more facts.

Comment: Ah, in that case make it a COM object but don't register it nor expose it via a Class Object at all. You can add a custom object to the environment when hosting VBScript, right? (I've never done script hosting, but IIS adds custom objects so it must be possible). Make one that acts as a custom factory object. I don think that VBScript's CreateObject is the right semantic for a private class like that.

Comment: First: CreateObject isn't needed from VBScript. But would be again a nice extension. The problem is that I need a spate thread (STA) to avoid some blocking problems. I am still asking for a way that thread 1 can create a COM objects from a different STA (thread 2) with standard CoCreateInstance functions. Thee are just a bunch of more things behind it. But my question is well formed now.

Comment: The problem here is that you have to use `CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER` in order to enable cross-apartment `CoCreateInstance`. And then this flag registers class factory session-wide and your second registration stays in shadow of the first one (only first process instantiates this `CLSID`). Supposedly the easiest - if applicable - is to register class object on the thread of supposed use, not on worker STA.

Comment: Again: I know what happens! But I need a second thread and I need a second STA. My question is still not answered.

Comment: Out of curiosity: the code that instantiates the class - is it something outside of your reach AND having its own STA it's running on? Because your question is confusing, why do you mention main STA then? If instantiation happens on main STA, just register your stuff there and do marshaling yourself. You did find already your secondary STA does not work out. You can register class factory on main STA and make its CreateInstance marshal secondary STA object pointer and pass it as return value.

Comment: All involved threads are my own created threads. OK I again explain more: The reason why I need two of them is that the main thread might be blocked inside the Active Script Debugging host. Now I need a different STA that is still accessible from my "external debugger application" that controls some interfaces and that allows me to call interfaces that are freely marshaled by the active scripting debugging... Please answer if you have a solution. I am tired to explain why I need this! :(

Comment: You are making it even more confusing now. "main thread might be blocked inside..." basically means that a thread that supposedly instantiates the class is blocked. For "external application"... why do you need STA exactly, and this is supposedly the same process. OK, what I see is that CoCreateInstance might possibly be a bad choice here, but since you insist on it and you don't want any workaround then I don't have a solution.

Comment: STA 1 need the object when the EXE starts up. This object must live in STA 2! That's all.

Comment: If that's all, you just don't `CoRegisterClassObject` and `CoCreateInstance`. You can still have fully featured COM pointer through C++ instantiation and COM API to marshal the pointers, or you could obtain the object via ROT and process-id specific name. You did not persuade you need `CoCreateInstance`, even more to this you mentioned above that you don't `CreateObject` from VBS at all. So it looks like you are ignoring other options you still have.

Comment: Right. That's it. I just store the IClassFactory in the IROT rather than exposing it with CoRegisterClassObject. Than I can access it from any thread I want and call CreateInstance. So I get my object created from anywhere I want and the IROT entry is still private to every application instance... Thanks Roman R.! Just write your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Putting something in the running object table (ROT) is not at all local to the process.  Although most certainly no one will look for your objects, they're still available for other applications.  Exception: [ROTView](http://alax.info/blog/1444), although it won't do anything with your objects besides listing a few generic properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is `CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER` makes the registration "visible" to calling apartment only and next option `CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER` makes it cross-apartment cross-process. That is, as you discovered, without specific option cross-apartment but within process, so that 2+ processes could expose class objects within their process scope.

Also it looks relevant that `CoRegisterClassObject` along with registration itself instructs COM to use the apartment of the call for further instantiation, and this prevents from registrations on thread that might be blocked, and even involvement of these apartments in marshaling of the pointers.

A workaround there is to expose class objects through Running Object Table using process specific names. Standard `RegisterActiveObject` would use "!{CLSID}" name and you are interested in names like "!{CLSID}-processid" (this flexibility is available through `IRunningObjectTable::Register` ROT registration instead of `RegisterActiveObject`) so that separate processes could look up their own object. Having ROT registration called from side STA thread would then result in marshaling calls there back directly bypassing "blocked" main STA.

Comment: Why use the running object table (ROT), which is session-wide, instead of the global interface table (GIT), which is process-wide?  Using the ROT implies looking up with a moniker and allowing access to other processes, which is unnecessary;  using the GIT and looking up a CLSID table is quite fast and keeps access to in-process only.

Comment: @PauloMadeira: Yes, you are correct, [GIT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678517) is another option when no external access is needed.

Comment: Both approaches (ROT or GIT) still don't make `CoCreateInstance` know about the new classes.  BTW, how would you fetch the object from e.g. VBScript (as per the op) from the ROT?

Comment: As the question states, `CoCreateInstance` is not necessary. VBS could use `GetObject` to get ROT's object exposed by `RegisterActiveObject`, however this should not work with customized name on ROT.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you want, you need to call `CoRegisterClassObject` for each new apartment.  To find out about new apartments, you can use [`CoRegisterInitializeSpy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679753(v=vs.85).aspx).

You should call it even before your first call to `CoInitialize[Ex]`.

In the implementation of [`IInitializeSpy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690179(v=vs.85).aspx) interface:

```cpp
HRESULT CRegisterClassesSpy::PostInitialize(HRESULT hrCoInit, DWORD dwCoInit, DWORD dwNewThreadAptRefs)
{
    if (hrCoInit == S_OK && dwNewThreadAptRefs == 1) {
        if (dwCoInit == COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED ||
            (dwCoInit == COINIT_MULTITHREADED &&
             InterlockedIncrement(&m_MTAThreads) == 1)) {
            hrCoInit = RegisterClassObjects();
        }
    }
    return hrCoInit;
}

HRESULT CRegisterClassesSpy::PreUninitialize(DWORD dwCurThreadAptRefs)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    if (dwCurThreadAptRefs == 1) {
        APTTYPE aptType;
        APTTYPEQUALIFIER aptTypeQualifier;
        hr = CoGetApartmentType(&aptType, &aptTypeQualifier);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr) &&
            (aptType == APTTYPE_STA ||
             aptType == APTTYPE_MAINSTA ||
             (aptType == APTTYPE_MTA && InterlockedDecrement(&m_MTAThreads) == 0))) {
            hr = RevokeClassObjects();
        }
    }
    return hr;
}
```

Because initialization spies are per-thread, you need to detect new threads.  The only (easy? supported?) way is with a DLL.

Here's an example (no error checking for clarity):

```cpp
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    if (fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
        g_tlsIndex = TlsAlloc();
        TlsSetValue(g_tlsIndex, HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(ULARGE_INTEGER)));
    }
    if (fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH || fdwReason == DLL_THREAD_ATTACH) {
        CRegisterClassesSpy *spy = new CRegisterClassesSpy();
        IInitializeSpy *pSpy;
        spy->QueryInterface(IID_IInitializeSpy, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pSpy));
        spy->Release();
        ULARGE_INTEGER* pCookie = reinterpret_cast<ULARGE_INTEGER*>(TlsGetValue(g_tlsIndex));
        CoRegisterInitializeSpy(pSpy, pCookie));
        pSpy->Release();
    }
    else if ((fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH && lpReserved == NULL) || fdwReason == DLL_THREAD_DETACH) {
        ULARGE_INTEGER* pCookie = reinterpret_cast<ULARGE_INTEGER*>(TlsGetValue(g_tlsIndex));
        CoRevokeInitializeSpy(*pCookie);
    }
    if (fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH && lpReserved == NULL) {
        TlsFree(g_tlsIndex);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Due to the unknown DLL loading order and unknown side effects of each library's `DllMain` (e.g. creating a COM worker thread), your `IInitializeSpy` implementation could be made more robust by detecting apartments it didn't know about more flexibly, but at that time, registering your class factories might be too late anyway.

For most practical purposes, this will work, it's just not reliable if your EXE depends on or dynamically loads such nasty DLLs before your own.

All this trouble is for:

- Keeping your class factories in-process
- Allowing access to them via `CoCreateInstance` as usual from any apartment

---

PS: If you intend to keep your class factory in an apartment (e.g. an STA), you should put it in the global interface table (GIT) so you can later retrieve a proxy to it from the `PostInitialize`, instead of having one fresh class factory per apartment, or worse, a class factory in an incompatible apartment.

Answer (score 1):

Roman. R already answered the question and I accepted it. But I want to explain the solution in detail that I choosed. It is a little simpler using the ROT.

1. When the Exe starts up, the second thread with the STA2 is created in the start phase.
2. I just create my class factory in my second thread (STA2) as usual
3. I don't expose this class factory using CoRegisterClassObject. I store the IClassFactory pointer in the IROT. I use the existing ATL implementation.
4. Now any thread inside my application that requires an object from this STA can retrieve the IClassFactory pointer from the IROT and can create the required object on behalf. The marshaling is done safely inside my application between the different STAs. Each EXE can store its own private copy of the class factory in the IROT.

So I have my private "per process" COM class registration.

Comment: With this approach, `CoCreateInstance` cannot find process-local classes.  BTW, how exactly are you implementing step 4?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you are calling `CoRegisterClassObject`.  The purpose of that function is to add your class object to the Running Objects Table, so that other processes can call it to create out-of-process objects. But you said you only want to operate within a single process.

You must have created your class object at some point, so why not just call `IClassFactory::CreateInstance()` on it whenever you need to create an object?

(I think you would need to marshal the IClassFactory from the class object's apartment to your thread's apartment; that can be done with `IMarshalInterface` or the global interface table)

Comment: If `CoRegisterClassObject` would really use the running object table (ROT), it would be an implementation detail you shouldn't depend on and it should only do it for `CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER`, not `CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER`.  It's `RegisterActiveObject` that uses the ROT, but that is usually used for global instances (e.g. an application) or specific objects (e.g. an open file), not class factories.

Comment: The op's purpose is to be able to use `CoCreateInstance` for COM classes known only to the current process, hence `CoRegisterClassObject` with `CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER`.  However, it only works for the current apartment.